# Should Azure Diagnostics be enabled for Production Deployment?

Tags: azure

I'm looking at performance improvements for Azure Web Role and wondering if Diagnostics should be left on when publishing/deploying to the production site. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/01/11/with-azure-sdk-1-6-azure-diagnostics-is-enabled-by-default-can-cause-thousands-of-daily-transections-to-azure-storage.aspx) says to disable it, but one of the comments say you lose critical data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should absolutely leave it enabled.  How else will you do monitoring or auto-scaling of your application, once it is running in production?

Whether you use on-demand monitoring software like [RedGate/Cerebrata's Diagnostic Manager](http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/) or active monitoring/auto-scaling service like [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com), you need to have Diagnostics enabled so that your instances are providing the external software with a way to monitor it and visualize performance data.

Just don't go crazy and enable every possible diagnostic data to be captured at the most frequent rate possible, but do so on a need basis.

Consider the reality that these "thousands of daily transactions" cost approximately 1 penny for 100k of transactions.  So, if you transfer data once per minute to table storage, this is 1440 transactions per server per day, or 43,200 transactions per server per month.  A whopping 0.43cents per server per month.  If the ability to quickly debug or be notified of a production issue is not worth 0.43 cents per server per month, then you should reconsider your cost models :)

HTH

Comment: Adding to @Igork's answer: I wrote a blog post about this a few days ago which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/10/03/understanding-windows-azure-diagnostics-costs-and-some-ways-to-control-it/